# Switching between browser instances

Tags: c#, selenium

I have multiple Selenium tests that I run in parallel. How do I "activate" the different browser windows (i.e. simulating a user click in the taskbar, making the window active)?

By default, Selenium's first browser instance is active and covers my other browser windows.

I've looked in to the other SO threads (java), and if I understand them correctly, I should keep track of all the webdriver instances "current window handles", and perform a switch in the following way:

```
activeWebDriver.SwitchTo().Window(someInactiveWindowHandle);
```

Is this correct? If so, how would I know which of my webdriver instances that are currently on top, so I know what to switch *from*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep track on the windows using `driver.CurrentWindowHandle`. This is a string that looks like

> "CDwindow-3E960650-3D6F-4083-939A-5887B46A5E23"

And used to identify the current driver active window.

```
string currentHandler = driver.CurrentWindowHandle;

// switch to new window
foreach (string handle in driver.WindowHandles)
{
    if (!handle.Equals(currentHandler))
    {
        driver.SwitchTo().Window(handle);
    }
}

//do something on new window

// switch back to old window
driver.Close();
driver.SwitchTo().Window(currentHandler);
```

> Usage example

```
Dictionary<string, IWebDriver> driversByHandles;

IWebDriver driver1;
IWebDriver driver2;
IWebDriver driver3; 

[SetUp]
public void SetUp()
{
    driversByHandles = new Dictionary<string, IWebDriver>();

    driver1.Navigate().GoToUrl(Url);
    driversByHandles.Add(driver1.CurrentWindowHandle, driver1);

    driver2.Navigate().GoToUrl(Url);
    driversByHandles.Add(driver2.CurrentWindowHandle, driver2);

    ...
}

[Test]
public void Test()
{
    foreach(KeyValuePair<string, IWebDriver> entry in driversByHandles)
    {
        if (entry.Key.equals(targetHandle))
        {
            entry.Value.SwitchTo().Window(entry.Key);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So `CurrentWindowHandle` can point to another browser handle, just not the current webdrivers? As far as I can tell, this only switches between windows in the same browser instance.

Comment: When you open new window you don't create new `WebDriver` instance, you just add another browser window to the driver's windows list (`ReadOnlyCollection<string>`).

Comment: Each of my tests has a separate webdriver connected to it.

Comment: Every `webdriver` should start with its own single `CurrentWindowHandle` (after opening the browser). You can save it and switch to it when needed.

Comment: Ok, but that brings me back to my question: How do I know which webdriver to switch _from_?

Comment: Do they have the same url?

Comment: Yes, they are testing the same page

Comment: Do you know which browser you want to go to? If you do `driver.SwitchTo().Window(handle);` should bring him to the front even if you don't know the current active browser.

Comment: Yes I do. I thought I had to use `currentActiveWebDriver.SwitchTo().Window(targetHandle)`. If not that will make things easier

Comment: I added usage example

Comment: Thanks, but with this in mind, why can't I simply do `driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.CurrentWindowHandle)`?

Comment: You need to switch as part of the test? because you can interact with the hidden browsers with the other WebDriver instances.

Comment: The question was based on the assumption that I needed to keep the browser window active that I was interacting with. But it seems like since Selenium is using the SendInput API, it works fine with all actions, regardless if the browser window is visible or not.